# Can a Fortran .exe be run within a ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, fortran, exe

I have some R code that creates a relationship matrix for sheep. The data I am dealing with produces matrices of about 500x500. The **pure R method of doing this takes around 30 minutes**. I have an identical (in terms of input file and output file) **code in Fortran, that runs in less than 1 minute**.

I am trying to **create a ShinyApp wrapper for this code**, and wanted to know if my ShinyApp will run, and be able to run the Fortran .exe or do I have to use the slow pure R code?

It will take time to hard code the ShinyApp, so I wanted to find out if it is even viable before pouring my time in.

Any suggestions or has anyone done this before and know that it does/doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your problem will be to transfer the data from fortran to R and telling Shiny that it is ready. But once you have solved that It shouldn't be to hard.

If you can run you fortran code from an R console (normally with something like `system("path/to/file.exe")`) you can do it in shiny as well.

I would probably solve it like this having the fortran programm putting the results in a csv file called `fortranOutput`.

```
system("path/to/file.exe")
while(!file.exists("fortranOutput.csv") i = 1
dta <- read.csv("fortranOutput.csv")
# continue data processing
```

hope this helps